# Como generar una lista doblemente enlazada circular automaticamente

Tags: java, enlazado

Buenas, tengo una pregunta como genero una lista doblemente enlazada circular automáticamente (me dan unos datos y el numero de nodos que debo crear).

Tengo el código de ingresarNodos, pero no creo que este me sirva

```
public void insertarNodo(Ruleta dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato);

    if (cabeza == null) {
        cabeza = nuevo;
    } else {
        Nodo temp = cabeza;
        while (temp.getSiguiente() != cabeza) {
            temp = temp.getSiguiente();
        }
        temp.setSiguiente(nuevo);
        nuevo.setAnterior(temp);
        nuevo.setSiguiente(temp);
        temp.setAnterior(nuevo);
    }
}
```

Clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {

private Ruleta dato;
private Nodo anterior;
private Nodo siguiente;

public Nodo(Ruleta dato) {
    this.dato = dato;
}

public Ruleta getDato() {
    return dato;
}

public void setDato(Ruleta dato) {
    this.dato = dato;
}

public Nodo getAnterior() {
    return anterior;
}

public void setAnterior(Nodo anterior) {
    this.anterior = anterior;
}

public Nodo getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}
```

}

He colocado la clase Nodo..

```
<p:panel header="#{bundle.titulo} #{beanRuleta.listaRuleta.contarNodos()}" id="pnlDatos">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.colores}"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{beanRuleta.nodoMostrar.dato.colores}" maxlength="25"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.posiciones}"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{beanRuleta.nodoMostrar.dato.posicion}" maxlength="25"/>

                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="pnlBotones">
                <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.btnGuardar}" update="@all" action="#{beanRuleta.guardarRuleta()}" ajax="false"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
```

El anterior es donde pido los datos (posicion = nodos a crear)

En el la clase Bean solo tengo lo siguiente

```
public void guardarRuleta(){

    listaRuleta.insertarNodo(new Ruleta(nodoMostrar.getDato().getColores(), nodoMostrar.getDato().getPosicion()));
    inicializarGrafico();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y este codigo falla porque motivo?

Comment: ¿Cómo está implementada la clase Nodo???

Comment: @gbianchi el codigo no falla, solo que necesito como generar la lista automáticamente (pidiendo por teclado el numero de nodos a crear).

Comment: @pablo-simon-diestefano Ya coloque la clase Nodo.

Comment: Y el codigo para generar la lista y pedir la cantidad de nodos a crear donde esta???

Comment: Si deseas generar la lista circular de un golpe utiliza un bucle de 1 al número de nodos y al final conecta la cola y la cabeza.

Comment: @gbianchi ya adjunte donde pido la cantidad de nodos, y la clase Bean, ya que lo estoy haciendo por jsfPage.